# How to ignore Snakemake's "params have changed since last execution"?

Tags: snakemake

Some very late jobs of a workflow crashed due to a conda environment not being active.

Now, when I try to rerun using `snakemake deploy_all --ignore-incomplete` all jobs are rerun straight from the beginning, with the following reason:

```
Reason: Params have changed since last execution
```

How can I make `snakemake` not rerun all rules, and accept whatever input there is already?

This [behaviour change](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1694) seems to be new since version 7.8.0.

Comment: If you are on snakemake >= 7.8.0, maybe you are hitting the recent [change in behavior](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1677). See if using `--rerun-triggers mtime` helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rerun behaviour seems to have changed in v7.8.0, see this announcement: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1694

To get the old behaviour back, one needs to append

```
--rerun-triggers mtime
```

`--touch` may work sometimes, but sometimes not.

When I ran `--touch` the rerun reason changed to

```
reason: Code has changed since last execution
```

Comment: This situation does seem to be a fairly common scenario, so there might be a better way to solve this (I don't know of any, though).